# Karger's Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, graph-theory, vertices, kargers-algorithm

I'm trying to implement the min-cut Karger's algorithm in Java. For this, I created a Graph class which stores a SortedMap, with an integer index as key and a Vertex object as value, and an ArrayList of Edge objects. Edges stores the index of its incident vertices. Than I merge the vertices of some random edge until the number of vertices reach 2. I repeat this steps a safe number of times. Curiously, in my output I get 2x the number of crossing edges. I mean, if the right answer is 10, after execute n times the algorithm (for n sufficient large), the min of these execution results is 20, what makes me believe the implementation is almost correct.
   This is the relevant part of code:

```
    void mergeVertex(int iV, int iW) {

    for (int i = 0; i < edges.size(); i++) {
        Edge e = edges.get(i);
        if (e.contains(iW)) {
            if (e.contains(iV)) {
                edges.remove(i);
                i--;
            } else {
                e.replace(iW, iV);
            }
        }
    }

    vertices.remove(iW);
}

public int kargerContraction(){

    Graph copy = new Graph(this);
    Random r = new Random();
    while(copy.getVertices().size() > 2){
        int i = r.nextInt(copy.getEdges().size());
        Edge e = copy.getEdges().get(i);
        copy.mergeVertex(e.getVertices()[0], e.getVertices()[1]);
    }

    return copy.getEdges().size()/2;
}
```

Comment: Your code looks fine, apart from the unexplained division by 2. Bear in mind that Karger's algorithm has a **low probability of success**, so you have to call it multiple times to be confident of finding the minimum number of cuts.

Comment: This is what i'm trying to find out. WIthout this division the returned value is 2 times the right answer and, curiously, always even. I execute the method a large number of times in relation of vertex number and I'm quite sure algorithm has been execute a sufficient number of times to find minCut.

Comment: Perhaps the `Graph` object you're using is set up for directed graphs? Try running your code with simpler test data. Like a tree, for example, which should have a minCut of 1.

Comment: Got the mistake. Thank you for your concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the problem was much more simple than I thought. While reading the .txt which contains the graph data, I was counting twice each edge, so logically the minCut returned was 2 times the right minCut.